# Increment Numpy array with repeated indices

Tags: python, indexing, numpy

I have a Numpy array and a list of indices whose values I would like to increment by one. This list may contain repeated indices, and I would like the increment to scale with the number of repeats of each index. Without repeats, the command is simple:

```
a=np.zeros(6).astype('int')
b=[3,2,5]
a[b]+=1
```

With repeats, I've come up with the following method.

```
b=[3,2,5,2]                     # indices to increment by one each replicate
bbins=np.bincount(b)
b.sort()                        # sort b because bincount is sorted
incr=bbins[np.nonzero(bbins)]   # create increment array
bu=np.unique(b)                 # sorted, unique indices (len(bu)=len(incr))
a[bu]+=incr
```

Is this the best way? Is there are risk involved with assuming that the `np.bincount` and `np.unique` operations would result in the same sorted order? Am I missing some simple Numpy operation to solve this?

Comment: Note that numpy.zeros(6).astype('int') is better written as numpy.zeros(6, int).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you do

```
bbins=np.bincount(b)
```

why not do:

```
a[:len(bbins)] += bbins
```

(Edited for further simplification.)

Comment: Would this not be slower, when b contains just a few large bin numbers?

Comment: Yes, it will be slower than a simple Python loop in that case, but still faster than OP's code.  I did a quick timing test with `b = [99999, 99997, 99999]`, and `a = np.zeros(1000, 'int')`.  Timings are: OP: 2.5 ms, mine: 495 us, simple loop: 84 us.

Comment: This works well. A simple loop has generally been slower in my program. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a similar way to accomplish this in a multi-dimensional case?

Answer (score 43):

In numpy >= 1.8, you can also use the `at` method of the addition 'universal function' ('ufunc'). As the [docs note](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

> For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to a[indices] += b, except that results are accumulated for elements that are indexed more than once.

So taking your example:

```
a = np.zeros(6).astype('int')
b = [3, 2, 5, 2]
```

…to then…

```
np.add.at(a, b, 1)
```

…will leave `a` as…

```
array([0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1])
```

Comment: This solution is the most elegant one AFAIK!

Comment: I'm trying to do this with a matrix, but I'm getting an error:

    arr = np.array([[1,3,5],[7,9,11]]);
    lIndexes = [[0,1],[1,0],[1,2]]
    np.add.at(arr, lIndexes, 1)


Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest posting this new question about multi-dimensional indexing as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

If `b` is a small subrange of `a`, one can refine Alok's answer like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros( 100000, int )
b = np.array( [99999, 99997, 99999] )

blo, bhi = b.min(), b.max()
bbins = np.bincount( b - blo )
a[blo:bhi+1] += bbins

print a[blo:bhi+1]  # 1 0 2
```