# Python: Fast way to create image from a list of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am doing the following.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab

.....

x = np.zeros([250,200])
for tup in tups:
    x[tup[1],tup[0]] = x[tup[1],tup[0]] + 1
pylab.imshow(x)
```

Where

```
tups = [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),....]
```

and `xi`,`yi` are integers

This is fine for `tup` with a low number of points. For a large number of points ~10^6 it is taking hours.

Can you think of a faster way of doing this?

Comment: "For a large number of points ~10^6..." --you mean for a picture 1000*1000? Does it really take hours?

Comment: No I mean for a tups that has 10^6 or higher tuples. I think I may have another issue that is slowing it down.

Comment: @medPhys-pl This one might help: [Increment Numpy multi-d array with repeated indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433142/increment-numpy-multi-d-array-with-repeated-indices)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small improvement i can easily see, instead of the next:

```
for tup in tups:
    x[tup[1],tup[0]] = x[tup[1],tup[0]] + 1
```

try doing

```
for tup in tups:
    x[tup[1],tup[0]] += 1
```

Since this overwrites the same memory-adress, instead of creating a new memory-spot to put 'old value + 1' (note: this will probably only result in a marginal speedup in this case, but if you do this same trick A+=B instead of C = A + B, in the case where A and B are numpy ndarrays of a Gb each or so, it actually is a massive speedup)

Why do you read in something as tuples? shouldnt you try to read it in as a numpy ndarray in the first place, instead of reading it in as a list of tuples and than change to a numpy array? Where do you create that big list of tuples? If that can be avoided, it will be much better, to just avoid the list of tuples, instead of creating it and than later swapping to a numpy solution?

Edit: so i just wanted to tell of this speedup that you can get by the +=, and at the same time ask why you have a big list of tuples, but thats too long to put both things in a comment

Another question: am i right in assuming your tuples can have multiple repeats? like

```
tups = [(1,0), (2,4), (1,0), (1,2), ..., (999, 999), (992, 999)]
```

so that in your endresult, other values than 0 and 1 will exist? or is your resulting array something in which only ones and zeros exist?

Comment: @medPhys-pl It will be much faster if you do not make a list of tuples in the first place though, so if you show where you make that list of tuples, it can be improved there as well (if you make it directly into a numpy array instead of first using the list of tuples and than going to a numpy array)

Comment: I've disposed of the tuples and stuck with a numpy array. It's not much faster though. I'll implement Jaime's suggestion and compare

Comment: @medPhys-pl but how did you make the numpy array, that is where you are slow, when you make a list, and than add 1e6 tuples to it, i think that is a speed bottleneck as well, (bottomline: how do you make your numpy array, when you no longer use the list of tuples? what does your input look like)

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy you could convert your pairs of indices into a flat index and bincount it:

```
import numpy as np
import random

rows, cols = 250, 200
n = 1000

tups = [(random.randint(0, rows-1),
         random.randint(0, cols-1)) for _ in range(n)]

x = np.zeros((rows, cols))
for tup in tups:
    x[tup[0],tup[1]] += 1

flat_idx = np.ravel_multi_index(zip(*tups), (rows, cols))
y = np.bincount(flat_idx, minlength=rows*cols).reshape(rows, cols)

np.testing.assert_equal(x, y)
```

It will be much faster than any looping solution.