# Expected behaviour for repeated numpy operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices, in-place

I found  this answer when looking for a problem on repeated actions on numpy arrays: [Increment Numpy multi-d array with repeated indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433142/increment-numpy-multi-d-array-with-repeated-indices). My question now is, WHY this behaviour is seen.

```
import numpy as np
t = np.eye(4)

t[[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]
```

leads to

```
array([1.,1.,1.])
```

so shouldn't

```
t[[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]+=1
```

lead to

```
[[3,0,0,0],
 [0,2,0,0],
 [0,0,1,0],
 [0,0,0,1]]
```

?

Comment: There's a buffering issue.  `np.add.at` is designed to get around that.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for indexing an array and the difference between basic and advanced indexing.

`t[[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]` falls under the category of advanced indexing and as stated in the doc:

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view).

The copy is evaluated before the first increment, so as expected,

```
import numpy as np
t = np.eye(4)
t[[0,0,1],[0,0,1]] += 1
print(t)
```

prints:

```
[[ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

As per the comments above, use `numpy.ufunc.at` or `numpy.add.at` to get around this.