# Update 2D NumPy array indexed with cross product with repeated indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm interested in the version of [Increment Numpy multi-d array with repeated indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433142/increment-numpy-multi-d-array-with-repeated-indices) indexed with a cross-product.

In particular, I want to perform the operation done by the following code using matrix operations to accelerate it:

```py
def get_s(image, grid_size):
    W, H = image.shape
    s = np.zeros((W, H))
    for w in range(W):
        for h in range(H):
            i, j = int(w / grid_size), int(h / grid_size)
            s[i, j] += image[w, h]
    return s
```

My idea was to compute all the `(i, j)` indices at once and use NumPy's `ix_` method to index the matrix `s`:

```py
def get_s(image, grid_size):
    W, H = image.shape
    s = np.zeros((W, H))
    w_idx, h_idx = np.arange(W), np.arange(H)
    x_idx, y_idx = np.trunc(w_idx / grid_size).astype(int), np.trunc(h_idx / grid_size).astype(int)
    s[np.ix_(x_idx, y_idx)] += image
    return s
```

It is easier to understand the code above with NumPy's example:

> Using ix_ one can quickly construct index arrays that will index the cross product. a[np.ix_([1,3],[2,5])] returns the array [[a[1,2] a[1,5]], [a[3,2] a[3,5]]].

In my case, it's likely that some indices will be repeated (as for example with `grid_size=2`, `int(0 / grid_size) = int(1 / grid_size)`). And that's where the [Increment Numpy multi-d array with repeated indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433142/increment-numpy-multi-d-array-with-repeated-indices) question comes.

In case the indices are repeated, I would like to update the matrix with the image value by the same number of times. I cannot get any solution to this problem without any additional loops (e.g., zipping the indices; but you essentially have to perform the actual cross product of the indices for `s` and the image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the best way to do it but here's one way.

```
import numpy as np

image = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
s = np.zeros((5, 5))
x_idx, y_idx = np.meshgrid([0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 2])
# find unique destinations
idxs = np.stack((x_idx.flatten(), y_idx.flatten())).T
idxs_unique, counts = np.unique(idxs, axis = 0, return_counts = True)
# create mask for the source and sumthe source pixels headed to the same destination
idxs_repeated = idxs[None, :, :].repeat(len(idxs_unique), axis = 0)
image_mask = (idxs_repeated == idxs_unique[:, None, :]).all(-1)
pixel_sum = (image.flatten()[None, :]*image_mask).sum(-1)
# assign summed sources to destination
s[tuple(idxs_unique.T)] += pixel_sum
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you run into problems caused by memory constraints you can do the image masking and summation in batches as done in the following implementation. I set the batch size to 10 but that parameter can be set to whatever works on your machine.

```
import numpy as np

image = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
s = np.zeros((5, 5))
x_idx, y_idx = np.meshgrid([0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 2, 1])
idxs = np.stack((x_idx.flatten(), y_idx.flatten())).T
idxs_unique, counts = np.unique(idxs, axis = 0, return_counts = True)
batch_size = 10
pixel_sum = []
for i in range(len(unique_idxs)//batch_size + ((len(unique_idxs)%batch_size)!=0)):
    batch = idxs_unique[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size, None, :]
    idxs_repeated = idxs[None, :, :].repeat(len(batch), axis = 0)
    image_mask = (idxs_repeated == idxs_unique[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size, None, :]).all(-1)
    pixel_sum.append((image.flatten()[None, :]*image_mask).sum(-1))
pixel_sum = np.concatenate(pixel_sum)
s[tuple(idxs_unique.T)] += pixel_sum
```

**EDIT 2:**
OP's method seems to be faster by far if you use numba.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def get_s(image, grid_size):
    W, H = image.shape
    s = np.zeros((W, H))
    for w in range(W):
        for h in range(H):
            i, j = int(w / grid_size), int(h / grid_size)
            s[i, j] += image[w, h]
    return s

def get_s_vec(image, grid_size, batch_size = 10):
    W, H = image.shape
    s = np.zeros((W, H))
    w_idx, h_idx = np.arange(W), np.arange(H)
    x_idx, y_idx = np.trunc(w_idx / grid_size).astype(int), np.trunc(h_idx / grid_size).astype(int)
    y_idx, x_idx = np.meshgrid(y_idx, x_idx)
    idxs = np.stack((x_idx.flatten(), y_idx.flatten())).T
    idxs_unique, counts = np.unique(idxs, axis = 0, return_counts = True)
    pixel_sum = []
    for i in range(len(unique_idxs)//batch_size + ((len(unique_idxs)%batch_size)!=0)):
        batch = idxs_unique[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size, None, :]
        idxs_repeated = idxs[None, :, :].repeat(len(batch), axis = 0)
        image_mask = (idxs_repeated == idxs_unique[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size, None, :]).all(-1)
        pixel_sum.append((image.flatten()[None, :]*image_mask).sum(-1))
    pixel_sum = np.concatenate(pixel_sum)
    s[tuple(idxs_unique.T)] += pixel_sum
    return s


print(f'loop result = {get_s(image, 2)}')
print(f'vector result = {get_s_vec(image, 2)}')

%timeit get_s(image, 2)
%timeit get_s_vec(image, 2)
```

output:

```
loop result = [[10. 18.  0.  0.]
 [17. 21.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
vector result = [[10. 18.  0.  0.]
 [17. 21.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
The slowest run took 15.00 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 5: 751 ns per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 195 µs per loop
```

Comment: I'm working with real images, in which case your method fails as it requires large amounts of storage. In particular, the instruction `idxs_repeated = idxs[None, :, :].repeat(len(idxs_unique), axis = 0)` prompts a `MemoryError` as it requests 2.78 TiB for a 486x900 image.

Comment: This time the `MemoryError`is prompted at line `s[tuple(idxs_unique.T)] += pixel_sum` when trying to allocate 269. GiB. Moreover, your code is slower than the brute force version with a double for loop. Thanks for trying it, though!

Answer (score 1):

Does [`skimage.measure.block_reduce`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.block_reduce) do
what you want?

```
from skimage.measure import block_reduce
s = block_reduce(image, block_size=(grid_size, grid_size), func=np.sum)
```

Comment: The only thing missing here is to only update the indices with non-zero value since I want to preserve the shape of `s`, i.e. `s[:int(W / grid_size), :int(H / grid_size)] = block_reduce(image, block_size=(grid_size, grid_size), func=np.sum)`. In this case your solution works *but only for integral values* of `grid_size`.