# Increment given indices in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Briefly: there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004364/increment-numpy-array-with-repeated-indices) and the best answer suggests using `numpy.bincount`. I need the same thing, but for a matrix.

I've got two arrays:

```
array([1, 2, 1, 1, 2])
array([2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

together they make indices that should be incremented:

```
>>> np.array([a, b]).T
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1]])
```

I want to get this matrix:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],  # (1,1) twice, (1,2) once
       [0, 2, 0]]) # (2,1) twice
```

The matrix will be small (like, 5×5), and the number of indices will be large (somewhere near 10^3 or 10^5).

So, is there anything better (faster) than a `for`-loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use [`bincount()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). The trick is to convert `a` and `b` into a single 1D array of flat indices.

If the matrix is `n`x`m`, you could apply `bincount()` to `a * m + b`, and construct the matrix from the result.

To take the example in your question:

```
In [15]: a = np.array([1, 2, 1, 1, 2])

In [16]: b = np.array([2, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [17]: cnt = np.bincount(a * 3 + b)

In [18]: cnt.resize((3, 3))

In [19]: cnt
Out[19]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 0]])
```

If the shape of the array is more complicated, it might be easier to use [`np.ravel_multi_index()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) instead of computing flat indices by hand:

```
In [20]: cnt = np.bincount(np.ravel_multi_index(np.vstack((a, b)), (3, 3)))

In [21]: np.resize(cnt, (3, 3))
Out[21]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 0]])
```

(Hat tip @Jaime for pointing out `ravel_multi_index`.)

Comment: +1 Very nice. [`np.ravel_multi_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) may come in handy to avoid having to think too much with more complicated arrays.

Comment: @Jaime: Awesome, thanks for the pointer. I was looking for something like `ravel_multi_index`, but didn't find it.

Comment: @NPE, I tried out ravel_multi_index and they don't seem to produce the same set of results. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450363/numpy-ravel-multi-index-increment

Answer (score 2):

```
m1 = m.view(numpy.ndarray) # Create view
m1.shape = -1 # Make one-dimensional array
m1 += np.bincount(a+m.shape[1]*b, minlength=m1.size)
```