# Numpy: increment elements of an array given the indices required to increment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to turn a second order tensor into a binary third order tensor. Given a second order tensor as a m x n numpy array: A, I need to take each element value: x, in A and replace it with a vector: v, with dimensions equal to the maximum value of A, but with a value of 1 incremented at the index of v corresponding to the value x (i.e. v[x] = 1). I have been following this question: [Increment given indices in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920070/increment-given-indices-in-a-matrix), which addresses producing an array with increments at indices given by 2 dimensional coordinates.  I have been reading the answers and trying to use np.ravel_multi_index() and np.bincount() to do the same but with 3 dimensional coordinates, however I keep on getting a ValueError: "invalid entry in coordinates array". This is what I have been using:

```
def expand_to_tensor_3(array):
    (x, y) = array.shape
    (a, b) = np.indices((x, y))
    a = a.reshape(x*y)
    b = b.reshape(x*y)
    tensor_3 = np.bincount(np.ravel_multi_index((a, b, array.reshape(x*y)), (x, y, np.amax(array))))
    return tensor_3
```

If you know what is wrong here or know an even better method to accomplish my goal, both would be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: Please show example input and desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `(A[:,:,np.newaxis] == np.arange(A.max()+1)).astype(int)`.

Here's a demonstration:

```
In [52]: A
Out[52]: 
array([[2, 0, 0, 2],
       [3, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1, 0]])

In [53]: B = (A[:,:,np.newaxis] == np.arange(A.max()+1)).astype(int)

In [54]: B
Out[54]: 
array([[[0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Check a few individual elements of `A`:

```
In [55]: A[0,0]
Out[55]: 2

In [56]: B[0,0,:]
Out[56]: array([0, 0, 1, 0])

In [57]: A[1,3]
Out[57]: 3

In [58]: B[1,3,:]
Out[58]: array([0, 0, 0, 1])
```

The expression `A[:,:,np.newaxis] == np.arange(A.max()+1)` uses [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to compare each element of `A` to `np.arange(A.max()+1)`.  For a single value, this looks like:

```
In [63]: 3 == np.arange(A.max()+1)
Out[63]: array([False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [64]: (3 == np.arange(A.max()+1)).astype(int)
Out[64]: array([0, 0, 0, 1])
```

`A[:,:,np.newaxis]` is a three-dimensional view of `A` with shape `(3,4,1)`.  The extra dimension is added so that the comparison to `np.arange(A.max()+1)` will broadcast to each element, giving a result with shape `(3, 4, A.max()+1)`.

With a trivial change, this will work for an n-dimensional array.  Indexing a numpy array with the ellipsis `...` means "all the other dimensions".  So

```
(A[..., np.newaxis] == np.arange(A.max()+1)).astype(int)
```

converts an n-dimensional array to an (n+1)-dimensional array, where the last dimension is the binary indicator of the integer in `A`.  Here's an example with a one-dimensional array:

```
In [6]: a = np.array([3, 4, 0, 1])

In [7]: (a[...,np.newaxis] == np.arange(a.max()+1)).astype(int)
Out[7]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and explanation. Sometimes I get lost in some answers but you explained it very clearly, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work this way:

```
tensor_3 = np.bincount(np.ravel_multi_index((a, b, array.reshape(x*y)),
                                            (x, y, np.amax(array) + 1)))
```

The difference is that I add 1 to the `amax()` result, because `ravel_multi_index()` expects that the indexes are all strictly less than the dimensions, not less-or-equal.

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you wanted; another way to make the code run is to specify `mode='clip'` or `mode='wrap'` in `ravel_multi_index()`, which does something a bit different and I'm guessing is less correct.  But you can try it.