# numpy: ravel_multi_index increment different results from iterating over indices loop

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array of indices (possible duplicates) where I increment each these of indices in another 2D matrix by 1. There have been several several suggestions and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920070/increment-given-indices-in-a-matrix?lq=1) proposes to use `np.ravel_multi_index`.

So, I've tried it out but they don't seem to give me the same set of answers. Any idea why?

```
raveled = np.ravel_multi_index(legit_indices.T, acc.shape)
counts = np.bincount(raveled)
acc = np.resize(counts, acc.shape)

acc2 = np.zeros(acc2.shape)
for i in legit_indices:
    acc2[i[0], i[1]] += 1

(Pdb) np.array_equal(acc, acc2)
False

(Pdb) acc[493][5]
135
(Pdb) acc2[493][5]
0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your current approach. Firstly, `np.bincount(x)`
will give you the counts for *every* positive integer value of `x` *starting at 0*
and ending at `max(x)`:

```
print(np.bincount([1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4]))
# [0, 2, 0, 3, 1]
# i.e. [count for 0, count for 1, count for 2, count for 3, count for 4]
```

Therefore, if not every location in `acc.flat` gets indexed, the length of
`np.bincount(raveled)` will be greater than the number of unique indices. What
you *actually* want is the counts *only* for those locations in `acc.flat` that are
indexed at least once.

Secondly, what you want to do is assign the bin counts to the corresponding
indices into `acc.flat`. What your call to `np.resize` does is to repeat parts
of your array of bincounts in order to make it the same size as `acc.flat`,
then reshape it to the same shape as `acc`. This will not result in the bin
counts being assigned to the correct locations in `acc`!

The way I would solve this problem would be to use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) instead of
`np.bincount`, and use it to return both the unique indices and their corresponding
counts. These can then be used to assign the correct counts to the correct unique locations within `acc`:

```
import numpy as np

# some example data
acc = np.zeros((4, 3))
legit_indices = np.array([[0, 1],
                          [0, 1],
                          [1, 2],
                          [1, 0],
                          [1, 0],
                          [1, 0]])

# convert the index array into a set of indices into acc.flat
flat_idx = np.ravel_multi_index(legit_indices.T, acc.shape)

# get the set of unique indices and their corresponding counts
uidx, ucounts = np.unique(flat_idx, return_counts=True)

# assign the count value to each unique index in acc.flat
acc.flat[uidx] = ucounts

# confirm that this matches the result of your for loop
acc2 = np.zeros_like(acc)
for ii, jj in legit_indices:
    acc2[ii, jj] += 1

assert np.array_equal(acc, acc2)
```

Comment: I understood the 2nd part about using np.unique. But I'm not quite sure I get the part about np.bincount being the length of np.bincount(raveled) will be greater than the number of unique indices. " Do you mind elaborating or stating an example?

Comment: I gave an example above: `np.bincount([1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4])` gives you the counts for indices 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4, whereas you only want the counts for the indices that actually occur at least once (i.e. 1, 3 and 4).