# Increment specific coordinates to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am very new to numpy and I wanted to increment specific locations of an array using numpy (so it is faster).

To be clear I have a list of coordinates in an array of "Info" class.

```
class info:
    def __init__(self, timestamp, position):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.position = position
```

For the moment I do this :

```
for data in datas:
    x = data.position[0]
    y = data.position[1]

    self.heatmap[x][y] += 1
```

"heatmap" is also a numpy array of size width and height.

I wondered if there was a more "numpy" way to do this.

**EDIT : What I was looking for is the world "indice", sorry. The answer is there : [Increment given indices in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920070/increment-given-indices-in-a-matrix)**

Comment: A sidenote. "Data" is a plural word. Its singular form is "datum". So, `for data in datas` should be `for datum in data`

Comment: where is the numpy array in all of this? what is `heatmap`?

Comment: Sorry, heatmap is np.zeros((width, height)).

Comment: It is not a duplicate of **that particular** question. I think the question is not about incrementing the indices. The question is about incrementing the value of the array at a given set of indices (based on the example given in the question), and based on the phrase"increment specific locations of an array ".

Comment: Hmm well you're right, but the way they do it in the other question do what I wanted to. Thing is I was looking for a fast way to do it (so that the for loop is executed in C)

Answer (score 0):

For example, can you use something like this?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
b = [0,0]
c = (1,1)
d = (np.array([2]),np.array([2]))
e = ([3],[3])
a[b] = 100  # b isn't a tuple so it doesn't work the way the others do
a[c] = 200
a[d] = 300
a[e] = 400
print a

[[100 100 100 100]
 [  4 200   6   7]
 [  8   9 300  11]
 [ 12  13  14 400]]
```

So you might consider

```
self.heatmap[tuple(data.position)] += 1
```

Comment: But will it optimise it ? In sense that this calculation is done in C and not in Python ? (Talking about the for loop)

Comment: Just did some performance test and it's not working.

Comment: you asked for "a more numpy way". Numpy *can* be faster than pure python under some conditions because yes it lets you call routines written in C. But for small arrays it often is not faster at all.