# numpy: How to vectorize aggregation loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector of zeros, and two arrays of *non-unique* indices and (complex) values. What's the fastest equivalent of this operation?

```
X = zeros(....)

for index, value in zip(indexes, values):
    X[index] += value
```

I would use `np.bincount` with `weights` parameter, but it only works for integer values.

Comment: Add sample case?

Comment: `X[indexes] += values` ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Thanks, but my indices are not unique. I edited the question

Comment: @Divakar: It's simply (index, value) pairs. I need to increase `x[index]` by `value`. The problem is that indices are not unique

Comment: Since you said bincount doesn't work. I am curious to see how it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah yes. This used to annoy me, but apparently, there is a new method, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28894452/5014455

Comment: @Divakar: It throws a `TypeError` for non-integer values

Comment: if `index` is used for indexing, how can it be non-integer. That's why a sample case could help on demonstrating why bincount doesn't work. Maybe  you are using it wrong? No sample case, not showing why bincount doesn't work doesn't really help us help you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Thank you!!!!