# Add 1 to numpy array from a list of indices?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array-like

```
x = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.int)
```

And I have a list of indices like `[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]` and I want to add 1 to the corresponding array elements, such that for each element in the index list, x is incremented at that position:

```
x = [0, 2, 2, 1]
```

I tried doing this using:

```
x[indices] += 1
```

But for some reason, it only updates the indices once, and if an index occurs more often than once it is not registered. I could of course just create a simple for loop but I was wondering if there is a one-line solution.

Comment: `x` is defined to be of length 3 but you later reference it as having 4 elements.

Comment: x is arbitrary and only chosen as an example, simple mistake :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increment Numpy array with repeated indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004364/increment-numpy-array-with-repeated-indices)

Comment: That link includes an answer that uses `add.at` that was provided to get around a buffering issue in `+=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are essentially trying to do, is to replace the indexes by their frequencies.

Try `np.bincount`. Technically that does the same what you are trying to do.

```
indices = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]

np.bincount(indices)
```

```
array([0, 2, 2, 1])
```

If you think about what you are doing. You are saying that for index 0, you dont want to count anything. but for index 1, you want 2 counts, .. and so on. Hope that gives you an intuitive sense of why this is the same.

@Stef's solution with `np.unique`, does exactly the same thing as what `np.bincount` would do.

Comment: my solution not only gets the number of occurrences but also adds them to the given array x. If you want to do the same with `bincount` then see the linked duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/a/2004468/3944322. (I admit that bincount is faster)

Comment: it doesnt, your `+=` in your solution is unnecessary, you are just replacing the indexed x array by its corresponding counts. same can be achieved with `x[idx] = cnt`. The benefit of += is when you are updating the values repeatedly, which you are not. So essentially your answer is exactly the same as mine, which is "replacing the indexes with their frequency counts:"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts` set to `True`:

```
idx, cnt = np.unique(indices, return_counts=True)
x[idx] += cnt
```

Comment: Technically, this is the same as `np.bincount`, as i show in my answer. You are replacing the indexes by their frequency counts.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal yes, but the question was not to get the number of occurrences of each index but to add 1 to a given array for a list of indices. So in my opinion you answered a different question (maybe OP had this in mind, but at least he didn't pose the question this way)

Comment: Actually, even your code doesnt incrementally add anything. The `+=` is unnecessary since you are not repeating the addition. the same result is achieved when you use `x[idx] = cnt`. so technically, you are also just indexing the array and then replacing it with its count, as `np.bincount` does.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal you need `+=` as OP wrote **"x is arbitrary and only chosen as an example"**.

Comment: I dont think thats the case, because OP says their arrays are zeros. but it could be a case as you mention it. in anycase, your answer is a sufficiently good solution to the problem.

Comment: in fact `np.add.at` is the correct method to do in-place addition with duplicate indices.

Answer (score 2):

You want `np.add.at`:

```
np.add.at(x, indices, 1)
x
Out[]:
array([0, 2, 2, 1])
```

This works even if `x` doesn't start out as `np.zeros`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, you can really just write

```
import numpy as np 
indices = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
x = np.array([indices.count(i) for i in range(4)])
```

Because `count` counts repeated elements. But the full solution would be

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.int)
indices = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
result = np.array([indices.count(i) for i in range(4)])
x += result
```